# Select graphic components when clicking on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, swingx

So I am having some trouble doing this. Basically I previously drew some line segments on a JPanel using Graphics2D and GeneralPath, and now I want to retrieve the Graphics2D/GeneralPath object when I click on it on the JPanel, is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to retrieve the Graphics2D/GeneralPath object when I click on it on the JPanel

You need to keep an `ArrayList` of `Shape` object that you draw. Then in the MouseListener you can get the mouse point and use the `Shape.contains(...)` method to determine if the mouse click was on a `Shape` you have drawn.

The `Draw On Component` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) demonstrates the concept of painting an object from an ArrayList to get you started.

Edit:

The `Shape.contains(...)` method doesn't work for lines.

Here is a quick attempt to write a contains(...) method for a Line2D object and a Point. Not sure how accurate it will be in real life.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

class LineContains
{
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        Point point = new Point(10, 19);
        Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(0, 0, 10, 20);
        boolean result = LineContains.contains(line, point);
        System.out.println( result );
    }

    static boolean contains(Line2D line, Point point)
    {
        double[] location = new double[6];

        PathIterator pi = line.getPathIterator(null);
        pi.currentSegment(location);
        int x1 = (int)location[0];
        int y1 = (int)location[1];

        pi.next();
        pi.currentSegment(location);
        int x2 = (int)location[0];
        int y2 = (int)location[1];

        double xDelta = x2 - x1;
        double yDelta = y2 - y1;

        double iterations = Math.max(Math.abs(xDelta), Math.abs(yDelta));
        double xMultiplier = xDelta / iterations;
        double yMultiplier = yDelta / iterations;

        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i ++)
        {
            int x = (int)Math.round( x1 + (i * xMultiplier) );
            int y = (int)Math.round( y1 + (i * yMultiplier) );
            //System.out.println(x + " : " + y);

            if (x == point.x
            &&  y == point.y)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working for me right now because no matter where I clicked, the point coordinates are always integer values and the contains() method is always returning false for me.

Comment: @LinxuanMichaelYang, looks like the `Shape.contains(...)` doesn't work on lines. See edit.